# Dynamically generate cases for switch statement using an array

Tags: php, mysql, rss, foreach, switch-statement

I'm creating a script to auto generate an RSS feed for the various sections of my website. I've queried by database and have an array of data which represents each section called `$showData`. I'm using a `switch` statement to setup various variables depending upon the section of the site. Instead of having to change this script each time I add a show, I'd like the `case` in my `switch` statement to be dynamic.

```
<?php
switch($section){
    case 'show1':
        $title = $showData['show1'] . ' Title';
        $description = $showData['show1'] . ' Description';
        break;
    case 'show2':
        $title = $showData['show2'] . ' Title';
        $description = $showData['show2'] . ' Description';
        break;
}
?>
```

I attempted to use a `foreach` loop to create each case, but you can't put that inside a `switch` statement. Someone else in another post I read suggested using `eval()`.

Here's my code that I tried, that doesn't work.

```
<?php
switch($showFilter)}
    foreach($showFilters as $key => $value){
        case $key:
        $title = $value;
        $description = $value;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Here's a `print_r` of the array

```
Array
(
    [show1] => The Name of Show One
    [show2] => The Name of Show Two
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using a `switch` block, could you not just try:

```
$title = $showData[$section] . ' Title';
$description = $showData[$section] . ' Description';
```

Comment: The beauty of the outside perspective, thanks! My original rebuttal was going to be about how some cases required special treatment, in those cases, I just used a `switch` to overwrite the variables previously defined.

Comment: It is not really answering the question... How to generate cases dynamically ?